# Get jqGrid ajax Nested Array of Json string in C# by Newtonsoft Json

Tags: javascript, c#, json, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm trying to parse Json string and collect array values present inside it.

```
{"_search":true,"nd":1492064211841,"rows":30,"page":1,"sidx":"","sord":"asc","filters":"{\"groupOp\":\"OR\",\"rules\":[{\"field\":\"Emp_ID\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"ASAS\"},{\"field\":\"Name\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"ASAS\"},{\"field\":\"Designation\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"ASAS\"},{\"field\":\"City\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"ASAS\"},{\"field\":\"State\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"ASAS\"},{\"field\":\"Country\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"ASAS\"}]}"}
```

> PS: Above string is coming from jqGrid Ajax to the WebMethod in C#.

I'm not getting success on getting **filters->rules[0]->data**

***What I've tried :***

```
dynamic jObj = JObject.Parse(postData);
var data = jObj.filters.rules[0].data;
```

getting error: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'rules'.

```
dynamic jObj = JObject.Parse(postData);
var filters = jObj.filters; //Sucess: getting filters here
var rules1 = filters["rules"]; //Error: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'rules'.
var rules2 = filters.rules;  //Error: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' does not contain a definition for 'rules'.
```

How to get value inside  **filters->rules** AND  **filters->rules[0]->data** ?

Comment: Are you sure that `postData` has string type and thus `JObject.Parse(postData)` is required? If you really need to make `JObject.Parse(postData)` then you still need to make **second** parsing `dynamic filters =JObject.Parse(jObj.filters);` instead of `var filters = jObj.filters;`

Comment: Thanks Oleg ! :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must parse the internal object like this :

```
var obj = "{\"_search\":true,\"nd\":1492064211841,\"rows\":30,\"page\":1,\"sidx\":\"\",\"sord\":\"asc\",\"filters\":\"{\\\"groupOp\\\":\\\"OR\\\",\\\"rules\\\":[{\\\"field\\\":\\\"Emp_ID\\\",\\\"op\\\":\\\"cn\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"ASAS\\\"},{\\\"field\\\":\\\"Name\\\",\\\"op\\\":\\\"cn\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"ASAS\\\"},{\\\"field\\\":\\\"Designation\\\",\\\"op\\\":\\\"cn\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"ASAS\\\"},{\\\"field\\\":\\\"City\\\",\\\"op\\\":\\\"cn\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"ASAS\\\"},{\\\"field\\\":\\\"State\\\",\\\"op\\\":\\\"cn\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"ASAS\\\"},{\\\"field\\\":\\\"Country\\\",\\\"op\\\":\\\"cn\\\",\\\"data\\\":\\\"ASAS\\\"}]}\"}";
dynamic jObj = JObject.Parse(obj);
var data = JObject.Parse(jObj.filters.Value);
var test = data.rules;
Console.WriteLine(data);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the knowledge about C# but I have tried into it on JavaScript

In your json, in filters field not is'nt proper json it is string

I have do this on javascript might it will help's you

```
var a = {"_search":true,"nd":1492064211841,"rows":30,"page":1,"sidx":"","sord":"asc","filters":"{\"groupOp\":\"OR\",\"rules\":[{\"field\":\"Emp_ID\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"ASAS\"},{\"field\":\"Name\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"ASAS\"},{\"field\":\"Designation\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"ASAS\"},{\"field\":\"City\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"ASAS\"},{\"field\":\"State\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"ASAS\"},{\"field\":\"Country\",\"op\":\"cn\",\"data\":\"ASAS\"}]}"} 

console.log(a.filters)
```

it is returns

```
"{"groupOp":"OR","rules":[{"field":"Emp_ID","op":"cn","data":"ASAS"},{"field":"Name","op":"cn","data":"ASAS"},{"field":"Designation","op":"cn","data":"ASAS"}
```

and it is string now i'm again parse into it on JSON

```
b = JSON.parse(a.filters)
console.log(b.rules)
```

now it returns rules objects

Comment: JSON string is coming from jqGrid, im not doing any modification with the string before sending it to C#. So string format should be correct. What are the mistakes in the filter field? Filter field i'm able to get (as i said in the  main topic). Actually i'm not able to get "rules" field.